# configure my home router

Tags: router, website, port, localhost, paypal

I need to configure my home router so my localhost website can be seen by the world.  I just need to configure the router because the paypal api's will not work with my localhost if paypal cannot get to my site.

Can someone please help me configure it?

I have a Linksys BEFSR41.

Comment: If you want to configure it "so my localhost website can be seen by the world." Then how does "The website is not intended for the world to be seen" work?

Comment: It will be seen by the outside world, what I meant was, it will not be a production server for the world to use.

Comment: Ideally, you should be able to go to the firewall section and open port 80 and send it to your IP address. If this is residential, it will likely not work though as most ISPs block websites for residential. You may need another port.

Comment: OK, so after forwarding port 80 to 192.168.1.200, how do I connect 192.168.1.200 with the folder where the website code is?

Comment: You should have web server software installed on your computer that allows you to go to the folder and place the files there that are public. In Linux for example, it is in /var/www/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to do:

- Install web server software on your computer if you haven't already. [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/) is probably your best bet.
- [Set a static ip address on your server.](http://www6.nohold.net/Cisco2/ukp.aspx?pid=80&login=1&app=search&vw=1&articleid=5454&donelr=1) This technically isn't necessary, but it's smarter.
- In the BEFSR41 use the NAT settings to [forward](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Linksys/BEFSR41/) port 80 to your statically configured IP address. Port 443 for HTTPS.
- At this point your website will be accessible by browsing to your public-facing ip address. You can find it by going to: http://whatismyipaddress.com
- You'll probably want to set up some sort of dynamic IP address updater.

That said, you're probably better off with a hosting account, but I can't really advise that well without knowing more what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: ...and welcome all the viruses and hacking attempts attracted by an open port on a residential connection. :)

I'm with emgee: There are plenty of really inexpensive web hosting services out there that'll host pretty much anything (legal, that is) with minimal work configuring on your end.